# How to make a prototype out of 2 identical controllers in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, angularjs-provider

In my app I have 2 almost identical controllers. A lot of functions are the same, so I'd like to prototype them. This is Controller #1:

**c2gcontroller.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('C2gCtrl', function($scope) {
    // some unique stuff
    $scope.feeDay = 59;
    ...
    // the identical functions
    $scope.getMinutes = function(minutes) {
      var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'm');
      return duration.minutes();
    };
    ...
  });
```

and Controller #2:

**c2gbcontroller.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('C2gbCtrl', function($scope) {
    // some unique stuff
    $scope.feeDay = 89;
    ...
    // the identical functions
    $scope.getMinutes = function(minutes) {
      var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'm');
      return duration.minutes();
    };
    ...
  });
```

I've tried putting `$scope.getMinutes` into a factory:

**smfactory.js**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .factory('smfactory', function() {
    return {
      getHours: function(minutes) {
        var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'm');
        return Math.ceil(duration.asHours() % 24);
      }
    };
  });
```

I've injected `smfactory` into c2gcontroller.js

**c2gcontroller.js (attempt #1)**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('C2gCtrl', function($scope, smfactory) {
    ...
    // the identical functions
    $scope.getHours = smfactory.getHours(minutes);
    ...
  });
```

This yields an error that minutes is not defined

```
 line 33  col 42  'minutes' is not defined.
```

So I tried:

**c2gcontroller.js (attempt #2)**

```
angular.module('c2gyoApp')
  .controller('C2gCtrl', function($scope, smfactory) {
    ...
    // the identical functions
    $scope.getMinutes = function(minutes) {
      return smfactory.getHours(minutes);
    };
    ...
  });
```

which doesn't yield an error, but my app did become unresponsive. Basically `$scope.getMinutes` doesn't return anything now.

I've read and watched a lot about AngularJS Services, Factories, Providers, but I don't know where to go from here. What would be the proper way to prototype `c2gcontroller.js` and `c2gbcontroller.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about pseudo inheritance with [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
/* define a "base" controller with shared functionality */
.controller('baseCtrl', ['$scope', .. 
    function($scope, ...) {

  $scope.getMinutes = function(minutes) {
    var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'm');
    return duration.minutes();
  };


.controller('C2gCtrl', ['$controller', '$scope', ...
    function($controller, $scope, ...) {

  // copies the functionality from baseCtrl to this controller
  angular.extend(this, $controller('baseCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));

  // some unique stuff
  $scope.feeDay = 59;

})

.controller('C2gbCtrl', ['$controller', '$scope', ...
    function($controller, $scope, ...) {

  // copies the functionality from baseCtrl to this controller
  angular.extend(this, $controller('baseCtrl', {$scope: $scope}))

  // some unique stuff
  $scope.feeDay = 89;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This is where using a combination of JavaScript awesomeness, and the `controller as` syntax really comes in handy.

If we pull your common functions out into a plain old object:

```
var commonStuff = {
   getHours: function(minutes) {
        var duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'm');
        return Math.ceil(duration.asHours() % 24);
   }
};
```

Then if we refactor our controller to be a normal JS object, we can augment it with a mixin one of two ways. Either directly onto the object itself, or via the prototype.

```
//Using the instance
function MyCtrl(){
   var vm = this;

   angular.extend(vm, commonStuff);

   //Other stuff
}

//Or via the prototype
function MyCtrl(){
   var vm = this;
}

//Controller specific
MyCtrl.prototype = {

};

angular.extend(MyCtrl.prototype, commonStuff);
```

The biggest difference is that now you can just reference the controller directly via the use of the `controller as` syntax.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.getHours(120)">Get Hours</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your profound answer! I decided to go with user2264997 answer as it doesn't break the Yeoman naming scheme.